# SQL Server 2008 sp1

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, asp.net-3.5

When I try to install SQL Server 2008 sp1 on my system, the installer runs and does the prerequisites check, every thing is ok except it says my machine has a pending reboot and won't continue until this is done. I Cold Reboot the machine,run the installer and the same message comes up. So I can't install the sp1 update. Any ideas ?

Info: OS Win XP sp3 x32 , VS 2008 sp1, SQL 2008 standard

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your help. Eventually I found uninstalling my logitech camera sorted the problem. SQL no longer reported it needed a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

The pending reboot issue usually indicates that a previous installation didn't clean up after itself. Look in your registry for this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
\PendingFileRenameOperations
```

Remove any values under that key and try the install again.

**LEGAL FINEPRINT:** *export and save, before making changes to the registry...blah, blah, blah...*

Comment: Thanks. However I don't have that reg key at all, is there any other place the system marks a restart

Comment: @David - another possibility is that there could some other program running in the background which may be accessing the same directory or registry keys that the install uses. Go through your Task Manager and terminate all unnecessary processes, then try the install again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rebooting it again? And again?  IIRC I had reboot several times on a fresh install (I try avoid installing SQL server).

Answer (score 0):

try installing from a command prompt using the /quietand /allinstances switches.
I ran into a similar problem with a service pack installation.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but the same error came back through the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure all your SQL Server services are stopped before starting the installation.